This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 8 but the current AGP requires Gradle JVM that supports version 17
I am trying to run a java android project below is the error I see on android jellyfish, I have below details of JDK and Java version
**
The Issue**
This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 8 but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17.
My details:
java version "22" 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22+36-2370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22+36-2370, mixed mode, sharing)
javac 22
JDK 22
Now provide me what should I write in my files and in build gradle version and AGP version
Trying to figure out

No one can tell you because you didn't share any details about the project. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make sure you haven't set any toolchain configuration on your gradle file. It sounds like your project is set to work on max version of Java 8.
Unless you need to enforce min/max java versions, you can remove toolchain support. This will allow gradle to use the Java version installed on the local device, instead of that on your gradle file.
You can find more info here.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html
And in your settings.gradle file, add this:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode = RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS
}

This will force centralisation of dependency management to use the config on your settings.gradle file instead of having each module manage their own repository settings.
It's now recommended since Gradle 7.
